# Android change language with setting menu

Tags: android, settings

Sorry if someone already asked but i could not really find an answer that works for me(link me if there is)
So i have a little test application where i try to change language with a settings acitviy.

On the first activty i have a simple text "hello world" from the string rescoure. I made a values-en and a values-hu(my language) and in values-hu i changed value of the string and i have this SettingsActivity where i can change the values (0 to Hu and 1 To English).

So the question is: How can i change the text(on the first activity) if i change the preference in my SettingAcitivity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the language setting and then let your first activity redraw the text, for example by going through onStop() and onStart() initiated from outside of your first activity or within your first activity by calling the drawing function and then calling invalidate().

Rudolf